# Sort Divs in two columns based on IDs listed in array

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have tried many different tutorials and threads to achieve what I am trying to do but to no help. Here's what I have and what I am trying to achieve:

```
<div id="column1" class="columns">
   <div id="5" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="3" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="1" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="column2" class="columns">
   <div id="2" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="4" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

The sort order is stored in an array:
order1 = [column1:{3,5,1,4}];
order2 = [column2:{2}];

Using the sort order arrays, I would like to achieve the following result:
<div id="column1" class="columns">
   <div id="3" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="5" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="1" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="4" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="column2" class="columns">
   <div id="2" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that possible for you to erase your div's content and to recreate it from scratch with your javascript ?

I think the easiest way would be to have empty divs (column1 and column2) and each time you have new data in your array, the goal would be to erase old div's content and to recreate it with your arrays content.

For exemple, your basic HTML will be like that

```
  <body>
    <div id="column1" class="columns">
    </div>

    <div id="column2" class="columns">
    </div>
  </body>
```

and here is your js (with jQuery since you post it as a tag) :

```
  var column1 = [3,5,1,4];
  var htmlContent = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < column1.length; i++){
   htmlContent += '<div id="'+column1[i]+'" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>';
  }
  $("#column1").html(htmlContent );
```

and do the same for column2.

You can also do a loop before this

```
  for(var i = 0; i < column1.length; i++){
   htmlContent += '<div id="'+column1[i]+'" class="dragbox">&nbsp;</div>';
  }
```

if you have a lot of columns to fill. Like that you can dynamically create your column's HTML.

This solution is correct **only if you don't need you column's div content** since `$("#column1").html(htmlContent);`
replaces the actual content of `"#column1"` with `htmlContent`

Comment: Thank you for your response and effort. This is just a sample code. The actual app will have two to three columns with 10-12 tiles in each column. I am afraid of removing the tiles and recreating might cause some data loss. These tiles (divs) have dropdown panels with related information as well. I appreciate the suggestion.